# Wireless network does not work in Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: wifi, connection, wpa

I moved my raspberry pi 4b to new place and found wireless network does not work.

I already set the ssid and password in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
and also tried to set wifi ssid and password through raspi-config.

the output of `ip a` and `ip r`
are
[image]

I also tried to down and up the wlan0 interface, but still did not work
`sudo ip link set wlan0 down` and `ip link set wlan0 up`

while

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 scan |  grep SSID
```

will get a list of wifi

some suggestions please.

Best wishes

Comment: raspbian gun/linux 11 (bullseye), thank you.

Comment: I just moved my raspiberry to my office from my home. and tried to connect the internet as I described above.

Comment: You are attempting to use inappropriate commands which won't work. You haven't actually explained what you tried. Do it properly by using the networking tab on the desktop.

Comment: there is no wifi icon on my desktop, no network manager.  what I did is to add ssid and password in my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf, but did not work. and I also tried to down and up wlan0 interfaces as the suggestion from web.

Comment: If there is no networking icon you have done something wrong. Unless you explain in detail WHAT YOU HAVE DONE no one can help

Comment: `and found wireless network does not work` did it work before you moved it?

Comment: DO NOT put details in Comments - edit your Question